# What is a good framework to implement data transformation rules through UI

Tags: java, user-interface, transform

Let me describe the problem. A lot of suppliers send us data files in various formats (with various headers). We do not have any control on the data format (what columns the suppliers send us). Then this data needs to be converted to our standard transactions (this standard is constant and defined by us).

The challenge here is that we do not have any control on what columns suppliers send us in their files. The destination standard is constant. Now I have been asked to develop a framework through which the end users can define their own data transformation rules through UI. (say field A in destination transaction is equal to columnX+columnY or first 3 characters of columnZ from input file). There will be many such data transformation rules.

The goal is that the users should be able to add all these supplier files (and convert all their data to my company data from front end UI with minimum code change). Please suggest me some frameworks for this (preferably java based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked in a similar field before. Not sure if I would trust customers/suppliers to use such a tool correctly and design 100% bulletproof transformations. Mapping columns is one thing, but how about formatting problems in dates, monetary values and the likes? You'd probably need to manually check their creations anyway or you'll end up with some really nasty data consistency issues. Errors caused by faulty data transformation are little beasts hiding in the dark and jumping at you when you need them the least.

If all you need is a relatively simple, graphical way to design data conversations, check out something like Talend Open Studio (just google it). It calls itself an ETL tool, but we used for all kinds of stuff.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply, the end users for this tool are not customers/suppliers but professional services/configuration team in my company itself. I agree about formatting issues, but still feel there should be frameworks that should be able to implement all this stuff. We would also be having error trapping mechanism for faulty data transformation stuff. Kettle and Talend are good, but pretty basic for my needs. I need something powerful and I am sure it exists ( may be a java template engine, may be something else)

Comment: Looks like your situation is rather a bit different from mine. It's just interesting that you call Kettle/Talend "pretty basic" - not that I want to advertise it, it's just that we did rather advanced stuff with it and it almost definitely offers a lot more than I would be able to do myself realistically. I would tend to see the situation the other way around: a full fledged ETL tool is overkill and I might consider building something simpler myself.